# Python - ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy, face-recognition

I am trying to implement face recognition by Principal Component Analysis (PCA) using python. One of the steps is to normalize the input (test) image `T` by subtracting the average face vector `m`: `n = T - m`.

Here is my code:

```
#Step1: put database images into a 2D array
filenames = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\Karim\\Downloads\\att_faces\\New folder/*.pgm')
filenames.sort()
img = [Image.open(fn).convert('L').resize((90, 90)) for fn in filenames]
images = np.asarray([np.array(im).flatten() for im in img])

#Step 2: find the mean image and the mean-shifted input images
m = images.mean(axis=0)
shifted_images = images - m

#Step 7: input image
input_image = Image.open('C:\\Users\\Karim\\Downloads\\att_faces\\1.pgm').convert('L').resize((90, 90))
T = np.asarray(input_image)
n = T - mean_image
```

But I am getting an error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Karim/Desktop/Bachelor 2/New folder/new3.py", line 46, in <module>
    n = T - m
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (90,90) (8100)`

Answer (score 3):

`mean_image` was computed for flattened arrays:

```
images = np.asarray([np.array(im).flatten() for im in img])
mean_image = images.mean(axis=0)
```

and `input_image` is 90x90. Hence the error. You should either flatten the input image, too, or not flatten the original images (I don't quite understand why you do it), or resize `mean_image` to 90x90 just for this operation.

Comment: images must be flattened to be 2D array instead of 3D to be able to calculate the mean, covariance, eigenvalues and eigenvectors. On the other hand, if the input image is flattened it would be 1D array and I also wont be able to calculate the mean, covariance, eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: @user2229953 I don't think it's needed for any functions that accept the `axis` argument, as @askewchan notes. Anyway, right now you're subtracting an 8100 1D array from an 90x90 array, which has to be fixed one way or the other.

Answer (score 3):

As @Lev says, you have flattened your arrays.  You don't actually need to do this to perform the mean.  Say you have an array of 2 3x4 images, then you'd have something like this:

```
In [291]: b = np.random.rand(2,3,4)

In [292]: b.shape
Out[292]: (2, 3, 4)

In [293]: b
Out[293]: 
array([[[ 0.18827554,  0.11340471,  0.45185287,  0.47889188],
        [ 0.35961448,  0.38316556,  0.73464482,  0.37597429],
        [ 0.81647845,  0.28128797,  0.33138755,  0.55403119]],

       [[ 0.92025024,  0.55916671,  0.23892798,  0.59253267],
        [ 0.15664109,  0.12457157,  0.28139198,  0.31634361],
        [ 0.33420446,  0.27599807,  0.40336601,  0.67738928]]])
```

Perform the mean over the first axis, leaving the shape of the arrays:

```
In [300]: b.mean(0)
Out[300]: 
array([[ 0.55426289,  0.33628571,  0.34539042,  0.53571227],
       [ 0.25812778,  0.25386857,  0.5080184 ,  0.34615895],
       [ 0.57534146,  0.27864302,  0.36737678,  0.61571023]])

In [301]: b - b.mean(0)
Out[301]: 
array([[[-0.36598735, -0.222881  ,  0.10646245, -0.0568204 ],
        [ 0.10148669,  0.129297  ,  0.22662642,  0.02981534],
        [ 0.24113699,  0.00264495, -0.03598923, -0.06167904]],

       [[ 0.36598735,  0.222881  , -0.10646245,  0.0568204 ],
        [-0.10148669, -0.129297  , -0.22662642, -0.02981534],
        [-0.24113699, -0.00264495,  0.03598923,  0.06167904]]])
```

For many uses, this will also be faster than keeping your images as a list of arrays, since the numpy operations are done on one array instead of through a list of arrays.  Most methods, like `mean`, `cov`, etc accept the `axis` argument, and you can list all the dimensions to perform it on without having to flatten.

To apply this to your script, I would do something like this, keeping the original dimensionalities:

```
images = np.asarray([Image.open(fn).convert('L').resize((90, 90)) for fn in filenames])
# so images.shape = (len(filenames), 90, 90)

m = images.mean(0)
# numpy broadcasting will automatically subract the (90, 90) mean image from each of the `images`
# m.shape = (90, 90)
# shifted_images.shape = images.shape = (len(filenames), 90, 90)
shifted_images = images - m 

#Step 7: input image
input_image = Image.open(...).convert('L').resize((90, 90))
T = np.asarray(input_image)
n = T - m
```

As a final comment, if speed is an issue, it would be faster to use np.dstack to join your images:

```
In [354]: timeit b = np.asarray([np.empty((50,100)) for i in xrange(1000)])
1 loops, best of 3: 824 ms per loop

In [355]: timeit b = np.dstack([np.empty((50,100)) for i in xrange(1000)]).transpose(2,0,1)
10 loops, best of 3: 118 ms per loop
```

But it's likely that loading the images takes most of the time, and if that's the case you can ignore this.

Comment: I am trying what you suggested but I am gatting an error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Karim/Desktop/Bachelor 2/New folder/new4.py", line 12, in <module>
    images = np.asarray([Image.open(fn).convert('L').resize((90, 90)) for fn in filenames])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 320, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
SystemError: error return without exception set`

Comment: OK I don't understand that error, but try to change `np.asarray` to `np.array`.

Comment: Alternatively, try what you have but get rid of the `.flatten`: `imgs = [Image.open(fn).convert('L').resize((90, 90)) for fn in filenames]`; `images = np.asarray([np.array(img) for img in imgs])`

Comment: `np.array` doesn't fix anything and getting rid of `.flatten` generates another error when calculating the convariance. Anyways, Thanks for your help